# AC in Closed Space

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I’ve rented space to build an art studio in an in-air conditioned space. There is a wall dividing the basement into two sections roughly 15’ x 30’. The space above is air conditioned. I would like to purchase a portable unit and run a pvc or steel vent to a window at the far end (30’ give or take). I’m concerned with water condensing in the vent, but could pitch toward window. [image]

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Comment: The question is....Will this work? Am I on the right track?

Comment: The manufacturer of the portable unit will have some kind of maximum exhaust distance listed, and perhaps recommendations in the installation instructions.  I’d be concerned about how strong the exhaust fan is.

Comment: A mini-split air conditioner may be a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you will get water condensing in the long vent. The exhaust air is hot and a PVC tube would have enough insulating value to prevent condensation. If you 
would use a flexible duct you might have to insulate it. This would also prevent heat from flowing through the vent and lowering the net cooling.